# CakePHP: -bash: cake: command not found

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-bake

I've used CakePHP a few times before but this is the first time I'm trying out Bake. On my Mac I'm running CakePHP 1.3, PHP5.3.3, and MySQL. I've created my database tables and the app connects to the database.

I navigate to the console folder. and type ./cake

I get welcome to the CakePHP v.1.3.5 Console. Then I gives me a list of shells to run. It says

> To run a command, type 'cake shell_name [args]'

I type:

```
cake bake all
```

and get

```
-bash: cake: command not found
```

Can someone help me out here? I'm not sure if I've missed something.

Jonesy

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have no experience with CakePHP but try prepending ./

```
./cake bake all
```

Comment: WOO! thanks. I'm not too clued up on bash stuff but this worked!

Comment: Thanks it also help me. Can you please explain the ./

Comment: @pkk Yes. Adding the `./` tells bash to use the file in the current directory. Without `./` bash will look for binaries in the `PATH` environment variable (which contains paths to `/usr/bin` and `/usr/local/bin` among others) and will therefore conclude that there's no `cake` executable in those directories and return `-bash: cake: command not found`.